# Need some help in lambda expression from SQL query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have this SQL query:

```
select 
    SubCaseNumber, MySaleries.WorkDate, stscreator.name,  Status, SheetId
from 
    (select * 
     from 
         (select distinct 
              Sheets.SheetID SheetID, ShtInfos.SheetInfoID SheetInfoID, 
              ShtInfos.Creator_Id STSCreatorID, ShtUsers.User_ID  STSFitterID, 
              Sheets.Status, ShtInfos.workdate, ShtInfos.SubCase_SubCaseId 
          from [Sheets]
          left join [SheetInfoes] ShtInfos on sheets.SheetInfo_SheetInfoId = ShtInfos.SheetInfoId
          left join [SheetUsers] ShtUsers on Sheets.SheetID = ShtUsers.Sheet_SheetID) AllSheets 
      where 
          (stsfitterID = '08153661-6520-4435-81e6-6064084db74d' 
           or stscreatorid = '08153661-6520-4435-81e6-6064084db74d') 
          and Status = 1) MySaleries
join 
    [SubCases] SubCases on SubCase_SubCaseId = SubCases.SubCaseId
join 
    [AspNetUsers] STSCreator on STSCreator.Id = MySaleries.STSCreatorID;
```

(returning 8 rows - correct)

And I have written the following Linq query to implement the SQL in Linq:

```
from Sht in Sheets
join SI in SheetInfoes on Sht.SheetInfo_SheetInfoId equals SI.SheetInfoId
join SC in SubCases on SI.SubCase_SubCaseId equals SC.SubCaseId 
join ShtUsr in SheetUsers on Sht.SheetId equals ShtUsr.Sheet_SheetId
join STSUsr in AspNetUsers on SI.Creator_Id equals STSUsr.Id
where (ShtUsr.User_Id == "08153661-6520-4435-81e6-6064084db74d" || SI.Creator_Id == "08153661-6520-4435-81e6-6064084db74d") && SI.Status == 1
select new {SC.SubCaseNumber, SI.WorkDate, STSUsr.Name, Sht.Status, Sht.SheetId}
```

Returning 50 rows - should bee 8 rows too.

I have following tables:

```
[SheetInfoes], [Sheets], [SubCases], [AspNetUsers], [SheetUsers]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 'Distinct' clause missing in your LINQ expression? Does that have any impact as per your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your join conditions in the SQL you posted are LEFT joins. Your joins in the code are just joins without any filtering.

Example:

```
from maintable in Repo.T_Whatever 
from xxx in Repo.T_ANY_TABLE.Where(join condition).DefaultIfEmpty()
```

I'd set it up something like this:

```
var query = (
from Sht in Sheets
from SheetInfoes
    .where(x => x.SheetInfoId == Sht.SheetInfo_SheetInfoId)
    .DefaultIfEmpty() // <== left join
from ShtUsr in SheetUsers
    .where(x => x.SheetId == ShtUsr.Sheet_SheetId)
    .DefaultIfEmpty() // <== left join
//You'll need to finish it
```

Take a look at this for a more info: [Left Outer Joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin)